# Catch when user defined ng-click executed

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have self written angularjs directive. For example `<directive></directive>`. User can add `ng-click` there like:

```
<directive ng-click="test()"></directive>
```

How can i catch when this ng-click executed, i need to call another function before `test()` everytime?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this link (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2422-Capturing-Document-Click-Events-With-AngularJS.htm) helpfull?

Comment: use it like this ng-click="otherFunction();test()"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against placing multiple functions in your inside ng-click="".  It is cluttered and can be confusing.  I would call that a code smell.

A directive like this should usually have a template associated with it.  In that template is where you would put the ng-click.  Then ideally you would use test() to initialize whatever flow of logic needed from your controller.  For ex in your controller:

```
$scope.test = function() {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
};
```

You can then place logic in this function as needed.  I hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a $broadcast event from the test() function and the catch it with $on().